# Why can I only change the height and not the width of an image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image of a player from the premier league's resources, then display that on a web page.
The images can be found using the link https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p178186.png. The 178186 is a code unique to a player and I can change that using jinja and the premier league api. So, I get the image on my page, but I can't change its width, only its height. I have tried declaring it when making the image in HTML:

```
<img src="https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p{{code}}.png" width="220">
```

I have also tried creating a class and then using css change the width:

```
<div class="playerimage">
                    <img src="https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p{{code}}.png" height="280">
                  </div>

.playerimage {
    max-width: 220px;
    min-width: 219px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 280px;
}
```

[Website showing the image appears, with the height altered to 280px, but no change in width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBJ2g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the img tag with css instead of the div with .playerimage, so this worked for me:

HTML

```
<div class="playerimage">
<img src="https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p178186.png" height="280">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.playerimage img {
    height: 280px;
    width: 10px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the problem is the `width="220"` attribute in the `<img>`-tag. If you remove this you should be fine and can change the height, width however you want and need to.

try this instead:

```
<img src="https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p{{code}}.png">
```